# Making A slideshow appear on more than first page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, responsive-design, drupal-theming

I am using the premium responsive theme in Drupal 7 to create a site. In the theme the front page has a slideshow on it. Is it possible to make the slideshow appear on the top of every page?

**EDIT**

So I was messing around with this a little more and I tried bringing the code into page.tpl.php so that it would appear on all pages, but nothing happened. I then tried doing it on the maintenance.tpl.php page, and still nothing happened. Any ideas out there?

Comment: The css says the display is block, but there is no physical block to move to a region no the interface.

Comment: Then check the page--front.tpl.php file.  If it's hard coded, then it will need to added to page.tpl.php to show on other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like we're working on a similar problem, but since you helped answer my question I thought I'd help you out. In the templates folder you have to create a new page--front.tpl.php (which I'm sure you have), and put it the code from this website:

[Go Here](http://www.thatagency.com/design-studio-blog/2011/02/creating-a-unique-homepage-in-drupal-7-using-page-front-tpl-php/)

This will make your front-page unique, and you can copy the similar code to your page.tpl to make changes to the remaining nodes.